# div hiding when selecting a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code for hiding a div if clicked outside the div.but i have a form in that div which is having an input type file.so when i select a file the box disappears as it take that a click outside the div.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $("body #new_discuss_form");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {

        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `var container = $("body #new_discuss_form");` should be `var container = $("#new_discuss_form");` The body tag inside the selector is useless as you are targeting the element using an `id`. It actually make the query takes more time as it will query the body tag first.

Answer (score 1):

Assign  `id="fileInput"` to your input type file and use below code :

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
var container = $("body #new_discuss_form");
if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0 // ... nor a descendant of the container
    && e.target.id!="fileInput")// if not input file
{

    container.hide();
}
```

Comment: Why add an id when `e.target.type` should return `file` anyway? More flexible to handle multiple ones without making the condition bigger everytime.

Comment: @techfoobar In the condition there is `&& container.has(e.target).length === 0 // ... nor a descendant of the container` prior it, so it has to be outside not inside the container. It's the last condition so other check have been made already.

Comment: @gillesc - You are right. I didn't notice that well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to achieve that.

```
function hideDivOutsideClick( clickedElem ){

     var divElemId  = '#new_discuss_form';
     var divElem    = $(divElemId);
     var parentElem = $(clickedElem).closest(divElemId);

     if(parentElem.length == 0 ){  //clicked element is not inside the div
          divElem.hide();
     }
}

$(document).mouseup(function (event){
     var clickedElem = $(event.target);
     hideDivOutsideClick(clickedElem);
});
```